# Mongoose: Part of array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this [**MongoDB**](http://mongodb.org) Notification Model:

- **User**: *Mongo ID*
- **Created**: *Date*
- **Content**: {}
- **Subscriptions**: [ {**user**: *Mongo Id*, **read**: *Boolean*}   ]

Using [**Mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/) in [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) I create a query that return all the documents where my user is inside the Subscriptions array.

```
 Notification
    .find({subscriptions:{$elemMatch: {user: req.user}}})  
    .sort('-created')
    .exec(function (err, notifications) {

        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {

            res.jsonp(notifications);
        }
    });
```

This query works, and returns the documents that I wanted... **But I don't want exactly this...** This code returns, in the documents returned, all subscriptions array, including other users. If there are 10.000 users inside the subscriptions array, all the users are returned in all documents.

**How can I extract a part of the array?** I want that only my user is returned inside the subscriptions array. **Why?** for security and performance reasons.

I tried this query:

```
    .find({subscriptions:{$elemMatch: {user: req.user}}}, {'subscriptions.$': 1})
```

This query only returns one user in the subscriptions array (my user). But... Is not returned any field more except the subscriptions array...

**Any suggestion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include other fields in your result like this:

```
.find({ 'subscriptions': { '$elemMatch': { 'user': req.user }}}, 
    { 'subscriptions.$': 1, 'content': 1, 'created': 1, 'user': 1 }
)
```